# All Watson Services are available in Lite account?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Are all the watson services available in IBM cloud lite account or some watson services are only available in paid account.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about developer questions, not product feature information. Please contact IBM with your wuestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Watson services are available with the IBM Cloud Lite plan with limits. You can find the available services and limits [here](https://www.ibm.com/in-en/cloud/free)

For Watson Studio, Knowledge Studio and Watson Machine Learning  limits, check the details [documentation here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/plans.html)